# How may I allow users to embed a view within a CKEditor text field?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, wysiwyg

I'm working on a site that includes a number of service pages (think practice areas in a law firm site) and each service has a number of identical content components (call to actions, legal disclaimers, etc) that are not always in the same order.

It would be *awesome* if there was a way for my content editors to add these components within the body field in any order they see fit. I believe the [CKeditor Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_blocks) module could accomplish this for static content, but for dynamic content I don't see a solution.

Sometimes the body looks like this;

```
{{ Paragraph }}
{{ Related Services }}
{{ Paragraph }}
{{ Call to Action }}
{{ Legal Disclaimer }}
```

and other times it's formatted like this;

```
{{ Paragraph }}
{{ Paragraph }}
{{ Call to Action }}
{{ Related Services }}
{{ Legal Disclaimer }}
{{ Paragraph }}
```

Specifically, the service content type has a 'related services' entity reference field and users need to include links to these nodes within the body of the page. Typically, if I knew these links were always presented at the end of the body, I'd just create a contextual view and present the results on the page (panels).

What are my options here? I've given some thought to using [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs), but that introduces more work than I'm interested in investing at the moment.

Comment: Paragraphs actually solves this problem very well and alleviates you from trying to make WYSIWYGs inject things and structure its not that great at. They can add X components to a node, change the order, and you can use Views as well (Views Reference Field).

Comment: I love the idea of panels, but I do it find it very cumbersome to interdigitate different paragraph types for the use case of a content body. Lots of UI in the way. I'm a markup snob, so dealing with all the Paragraphs/entity templates gets labor intensive as well. Have any resources for improving the UX of Paragraphs?

Comment: ^ "the idea of paragraphs" rather.

Comment: One way to do a view is to use a token. https://www.drupal.org/project/token_embed_views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as embedding a view into CKEditor, you can use a formula with Token Embed Views and or Token Insert:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/token_embed_views
- https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert